# match category name with jquery array and hide specific div

Tags: jquery, bigcommerce

i want to hide and show the div id="brandmenu" based on category name exist on on array..
if array contains category name then show this div otherwise hide this div.

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    var brandmenu = $("#brandmenu");
    var catName = "Activewear";
    var myarr = ["Activewear", "Anvil", "Bulwark", "CornerStone", "District", "District Made", "Fruit of the Loom", "Gildan", "Hanes", "Jerzees", "Port & Company", "Port Authority", "Precious Cargo", "Red House", "Red Kap", "Russell Outdoors", "Sport-Tek"];
    var arraycontainsturtles = (myarr.indexOf(catName) > -1);
    if(arraycontainsturtles == true) {
       brandmenu.show();
    } else {
       brandmenu.hide();
    }
    </script>
    <div id="brandmenu" style="display:none;">
      content to hide and show
    </div>
```

Comment: what's your question?

Comment: i want to show div id="brandmenu" on specific category pages.. like {{category.name}} is CornerStone. when i goto  CornerStone category then div should be visible.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to iterate over each `li` then Find html of `a` tag. find that word in your array. then show/hide it.

```
var brandmenu = $("#brandmenu");
    var myarr = ["Anvil", "Bulwark", "CornerStone", "District", "District Made", "Fruit of the Loom", "Gildan", "Hanes", "Jerzees", "Port & Company", "Port Authority", "Precious Cargo", "Red House", "Red Kap", "Russell Outdoors", "Sport-Tek"];

    $('.navList > li').each(function(index,val){
        var catName = $(this).find('a').html();
        var arraycontainsturtles = (myarr.indexOf(catName) > -1);
         if(arraycontainsturtles == true) {
            $(this).show();
          } else {
           $(this).hide();
         }
    });
```

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cvn7pyra/)**

Comment: var catName = "{{category.name}}"; //category.name is dynamic value.. bigcommerce stencil variable.. i guess i'm on the right track. :)